# How to add new user and pin to this list?

Tags: python

how do i had new user and pin to this list

```
users = {'name': '1234', 'name2': '5678', 'name3': '9012'}
status = ""

if status == "n":

    create_userName = raw_input("Create login name: ")

    if create_userName in users: # check if login name exists
        print "\nLogin name already exist!\n"

    else:
        create_passWord = raw_input("Create password: ")
        users[create_userName] = create_passWord # add login and password
        print("\nUser created!\n")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: am trying to add new user name and pin to the above list in users

Comment: That is not clear enough. Do you want us to modify the above code for you? Just how is that code not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: `status` never becomes `"n"`, so nothing inside `if` block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is your question but I just removed that

```
if status = "n":
```

part because with that part the program would never execute cause status will never become 'n' ...

```
users = {'name': '1234', 'name2': '5678', 'name3': '9012'}
create_userName = input("Create login name: ")
if create_userName in users: # check if login name exists
    print ("\nLogin name already exist!\n")

else:
    create_passWord = input("Create password: ")
    users[create_userName] = create_passWord # add login and password
    print("\nUser created!\n")
```

I hope this is helpful.